# What is unexpected EOF while parsing in the following code?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, loops, user-input

The is how the code looks:

```
import re
t=int(input())
for i in range(t):
    s=str(input())
    print(bool(re.match(r"\d",s)))
```

Comment: Works fine in Python 3.x ?

Comment: NO sir! It doesn't

Comment: what is the input you give, and what is the exact error?

Comment: I'm running it in IntelliJ and it's working fine. It's breaking on ideone.com online compiler

Comment: Error: https://ideone.com/xofdD5

Comment: Compiled without input(): https://ideone.com/DFtPCp

Comment: This works fine on ipython with python3.6